# Jquery Validation not working when id is diffrent than name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have a simple HTML Form and i am trying to validate it using Jquery Validation but for some reason the form is not being validated. Please help.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <form novalidate="novalidate" action="http://talentcapture.com/Profile/save_profile" id="update-profile-form" method="POST" class="validateForm">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Update Your Profile Information</legend>
                       <div class="form-group">
                           <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
                              <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
                           </label>
                           <div class="col-md-8">
                              <input name="users[first_name]" value="Jhon" data-required="true" id="users-first_name" class="form-control" type="text">
                              <span class="help-block"></span>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="form-group">
                           <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
                               <label for="user_name">Last Name:</label>
                           </label>
                           <div class="col-md-8">
                               <input name="users[last_name]" value="Doe" data-required="true" id="users-last_name" class="form-control" type="text">
                               <span class="help-block"></span>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="form-group">
                           <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
                               <label for="street_address">Street Address:</label>
                           </label>
                           <div class="col-md-8">
                               <input name="user_profiles[street_address]" value="" data-required="true" id="user_profiles-street_address" class="form-control" type="text">
                               <span class="help-block"></span>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="form-group">
                           <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
                                <label for="locality">Locality:</label>                       </label>
                           <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input name="user_profiles[locality]" value="" data-required="true" id="user_profiles-locality" class="form-control" type="text">
                                <span class="help-block"></span>
                           </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                           <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
                                <label for="city">City:</label>
                           </label>
                           <div class="col-md-8">
                                 <input name="user_profiles[city]" value="" data-required="true" id="user_profiles-city" class="form-control" type="text">
                                 <span class="help-block"></span>
                           </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                           <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
                                <label for="state">State:</label>                       </label>
                           <div class="col-md-8">
                                 <input name="user_profiles[state]" value="" data-required="true" id="user_profiles-state" class="form-control" type="text">
                                 <span class="help-block"></span>
                           </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                           <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
                                   <label for="country">Country:</label>                       </label>
                           <div class="col-md-8">
                                  <input name="user_profiles[country]" value="" data-required="true" id="user_profiles-country" class="form-control" type="text">
                                  <span class="help-block"></span>
                           </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                           <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
                                 <label for="zipcode">Zipcode:</label>                       </label>
                           <div class="col-md-8">
                                 <input name="user_profiles[zipcode]" value="" data-required="true" data-number="true" id="user_profiles-zipcode" class="form-control" type="text">
                                 <span class="help-block"></span>
                            </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
                                  <label for="company_name">Company name:</label>
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <input name="user_profiles[company_name]" value="" data-required="true" id="user_profiles-company_name" class="form-control" type="text">
                                    <span class="help-block"></span>
                            </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
                               <label for="company_desc">Company Description:</label>
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <textarea name="user_profiles[company_desc]" cols="40" rows="10" type="textarea" data-required="true" id="user_profiles-company_desc" class="form-control"></textarea>

                                <span class="help-block"></span>
                            </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
                                <label for="linkedin_url">Linkedin url :</label>
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                 <input name="user_profiles[linkedin_url]" value="" data-required="true" id="user_profiles-linkedin_url" class="form-control" type="text">
                                 <span class="help-block"></span>
                            </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="form-group">
                             <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
                                    <label for="company_website_url">Company Website:</label>
                             </label>
                             <div class="col-md-8"><input name="user_profiles[company_website_url]" value="" data-required="true" id="user_profiles-company_website_url" class="form-control" type="text">
                              <span class="help-block"></span>
                       </div>
                  </div> 
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
           </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I have this common method to validate all my forms based on the data- attribute passed to the fields.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var form = $(".validateForm");
form.each(function(){
    var validationRules = {};
    var field = '';
    $(this).find(':input').each(function(){
        field = $(this).attr('id');
        if(typeof field !== 'undefined')
            validationRules[field]= $(this).data();
    });
    var error = $('.alert-error', $(this));
    var success = $('.alert-success', $(this));
    console.log(validationRules);
    $(this).validate({
        rules: validationRules,
        errorClass : 'help-inline error-msg',
        errorElement: 'span',
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) { // render error placement for each input type

            var type = $(element).prop('type');
            if(type == 'checkbox' || type == 'radio'){
                error.insertAfter(element.closest('.'+type));
                error.css('float','none');
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element); // for other inputs, just perform default behavoir
            }
        },

        invalidHandler: function (event, validator) { //display error alert on form submit
            success.hide();
            error.show();
        },

        highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
        },

        unhighlight: function (element) { // revert the change dony by hightlight
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success'); // set error class to the control group
        },

    });
});
```

however the Validation does not work and the form gets submitted on blank fields even though all fields are mandatory.

Comment: what is that:  novalidate="novalidate" on the form?

Comment: are you getting any console errors?

Comment: jquery validate supports `name` not `id`. You need to specify a new rule for that.

Comment: @Harry No no console errors

Comment: @Developer107 how do i do that ?

Comment: @AngryCoder For new rule, please see this - https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-validate-validating-on-input-id-instead-of-name#14737000002034857

Or you can use `field = $(this).attr('name');` instead of `field = $(this).attr('id');`